# Compile time constants as floats

Tags: c, floating-point, compile-time-constant

After converting a file with doubles to floats the compiler (MSCV2005) warns about conversions from `double` to `float` for in code constants like

```
...
float r;

r = (q1 + q2) * 0.5;
...
```

Even `q1, q2` are both floats `0.5` seems to be treated as `double`.

How to adapt this behavious, so that all in-code constants are treated as `float`s?

Comment: It's actually **double** and not **float** that is the "normal" floating-point type in C. Functions like **sin** and **log** take doubles as arguments, and they return doubles. Floating-point literals such as **0.5** have type double, not float. Because of this, it takes some effort to use float in calculations instead of double: **sinf**, **logf**, **0.5f**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an `f` suffix to indicate that the constant is to have type `float`:

```
float q1 = ...;
float q2 = ...;
float r = (q1 + q2) * 0.5f;
```

The standard (§6.4.4.2 Floating constants) says:

> An unsuffixed floating constant has type `double`. If suffixed by the letter `f` or `F`, it has
>   type `float`. If suffixed by the letter `l` or `L`, it has type `long double`.

The constant in your question has no suffix and so has type `double`.

Answer (score 5):

Just add `f`after the constant:

```
float f = 0.5f;
```